# How to create a nested sequence in bash?

Tags: bash, seq

I have to create a nested Sequence in bash script like a1b1 a1b2 ab3 a2b1 a2b2 a2b3.
The upper limit of both the sequences will be taken via command line argument.

I came to know about `seq command` but with this I am able to create only single sequence.
I used this statement `echo $(seq -f "a%g" 8)`.
Is there a way to create the nested sequence using seq command or by any other way.
Note: I tried with expansion braces but it won't work as I have to take the limits from command line argument.

Answer (score 3):

```
$for i in $(seq 2); do for j in $(seq 3); do  echo "a${i}b${j}"; done; done;
a1b1
a1b2
a1b3
a2b1
a2b2
a2b3
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method is using GNU parallel (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
a=$(seq -f "a%g" 8)
b=$(seq -f "b%g" 8)
parallel echo {} ::: $a ::: $b
```

NB. If you need the output in the correct order use `parallel --keep-order echo {} ::: $a ::: $b` or pipe the results to `sort` e.g. `parallel echo {} ::: $a ::: $b | sort`

Comment: This is especially useful if the nested sequence is really just a step to generate arguments that each will be run by the same command.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, and that's what I believe OP is trying to do based on his comment: "Note: I tried with expansion braces but it won't work as I have to take the limits from command line argument"

Answer (score 1):

Following does your job. Simply you have to implement some sort of looping mechanism

```
for i in `seq -f "a%g" 2`
do
   for j in `seq -f "b%g" 3`
   do
      echo $i$j
   done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just brace expansion from bash

```sh
printf '%s\n' a{1..2}b{1..3}
```

Output

```
a1b1
a1b2
a1b3
a2b1
a2b2
a2b3
```